# How can I create a VIEW which uses additional columns to show data from multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, foreach, pivot-table

I've got a MySQL dataset which was developed by a programmer who didn't enforce the conditions requested by the customer. Instead of page timings as a user progresses through a website being individually stored in a '`Responses`' table, on a per user basis, they're stored in a '`Timings`' table in the following format:

- `TimingID` <sup>(int, PK, autoinc)</sup> e.g. 6673
- `UserID` <sup>(int)</sup> e.g. 226
- `Website` <sup>(varchar)</sup> e.g. Site1
- `Page` <sup>(varchar)</sup> e.g. Page1
- `StartTime` <sup>(datetime)</sup> e.g. 2019-05-04 15:40:10
- `EndTime` <sup>(datetime)</sup> e.g. 2019-05-04 15:40:50

Using something like:

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM page_timings WHERE UserID IS NOT NULL 
 ORDER BY UserID, TimingID`

gives me the '`Timings`' data ordered as I want to display it initially but I'd like to join it to another table for export and append each user's data to one row/UserID for processing in SPSS. Ideally the code would create columns in the format of

`UserID`, `Site1Page1_TimingID`, `Site1Page1_StartTime`, `Site1Page1_EndTime`, `Site1Page2_TimingID`, `Site1Page2_StartTime`, `Site1Page2_EndTime`, `Site2Page1_TimingID`, `Site2Page1_StartTime`, `Site2Page1_EndTime`

There are 2 'Sites', one with 8 pages and one with 20. Users may or may not visit specific pages and always have the same order of visiting. As I've no access to the webserver or suchlike I can't cobble together a solution in PHP and I can't use a pivot table as MySQL doesn't support them. I've got as far as *probably* using `CASE` statements and `GROUP BY` but unsure of how to make things work, other than that it would use `MAX` rather than `SUM` on the `Site` and `Page` names as I'm not working with numeric data in those fields, or using `GROUP_CONCAT` and `DISTINCT`?

Please could someone demonstrate which of the thousands of StackOverflow answers I've missed which answer my question (have spent >30 mins searching) or help with specific code as to how (best) to do this, and explain which of the options available will perform best on a small (<10mb) recordset. Ideally using `CREATE VIEW` as the data will need to be easily accessed longer term via SQLyog or similar.

Thankyou!

Comment: This sounds like a job for SPSS rather than mysql. If that's not possible a view cannot do anything a query cannot do so a view is not going to be helpful you should consider dynamic sql. MYSQL does not have pivot but you should google mysql pivot and/or mysql conditional aggregation and/or mysql prepared statements for alternatives some of which probably use dynamic sql

Comment: @portll . . . And what if a user visits the same page multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

If users visit a page only once, then you can do a pivot with conditional aggregation:

```
select userid,
       max(case when website = 'site1' and page = 'page1' then starttime end) as site1page1_starttime,
       max(case when website = 'site1' and page = 'page1' then endtime end) as site1page1_endtime,
       max(case when website = 'site1' and page = 'page2' then starttime end) as site1page2_starttime,
       max(case when website = 'site1' and page = 'page2' then endtime end) as site1page2_endtime,
from timings,
       . . .  -- and so on for all the sites and pages
group by userid;
```

This operation is referred to as "pivoting" the data.

Comment: Multiple from statements in a query - did you type this right @Gordon Linoff